# Custom ActionFilter to check the existence of the parametre in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

Hi there I am looking for a solution to solve this problem.I am building an Web app with Asp.net mvc3.
I want to make a custom Action Filter ([KeyAuthorization]) so that only authorized key will access the controllers.

This is my default Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
               "{guid}/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
               new { guid = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Home", action = "Index", }
```

So let say someone access the  **www.example.com/34safd-234s/home/index**

if key:34safd-234s is correct (authorized) than the user will see the content otherwise the web app will throw an 404.

How can achieve this?

Thank you,

How can I build and action filter that checkes that guid parametre exist in the

Comment: Using an action filter to check some value in database makes sense only if you need this logic on more actions, otherwise it would be better to check value inside an action and than choose which view to return.

Comment: Another approach is using Route Constraint http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx

Comment: Yes I need it on all actions, is some kind of api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating an `ActionFilterAttribute`. This should get you going in the right direction. You'll need to do your validation where commented.

```
public class KeyAuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        var guidValue = filterContext.RouteData.Values["guid"];
        if (guidValue != null) {
            Guid guid = new Guid(guidValue.ToString());
            bool notValid = true;
            //do validation
            //set notValid = false if authorization passes             

            if (notValid) {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would then apply this to your action.

```
[KeyAuthorization]
public ActionResult Index() {
}
```

Comment: Thankyouuuu BuildStarted this is what I was looking for